# Jsp Quiz Saving Responses Temprary

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am working on a Quiz Assessment System in jsp. I want to Store the user responses Temp.(Save the Response as He/she Clicks particular Radio Button). How can i store these responses.n what will be Safe & Easy to use?

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: Session? It's unclear what you're really trying to do.

Comment: let me make it clear to you...i have 30 boxes to navigate to 30 questions.whenever a user clicks a particular box.via an ajax call user get particular question from database.Now the problem is i want to maintain the states of the radio buttons answered by the users.so i can maintain the users answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use local cookies. Using html JavaScript. Then have a function in your header page (I hope you have a header inclde jsp or one main jsp that shows each question)

Either way -> there will be common java script on each page to save, delete and get a cookie, and then init the controls.

Another way would be to use the session but that would add to RAM usage on the server, but its more secure. But in this case when you only want to save the state of a multi page form I would use cookies on the client and then destroy them when the form is being finally submitted (life of cookie can be this session and you can explicitly remove them on final submit).

Do you need code for cookies ? Can get that by searching [example](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+javascript+cookie+read+write+delete&)

Once a user navigates back to a page the cookie for that question(s) would tell you which radio button to select. To select a particular button this [search would help](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+javascript+set+radio+button) its on the lines of :
    document.getElementById('q1ans1').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('q1ans2').checked = true;

If you want a loop/ data driven approcah can use java script eval to get each radio button like so :
obj1 = eval("q" + questionNumber + "ans" + ansLoop)
obj1.checked = cookieValueWithDefault;

Comment: Thanks for your ideas one more option is i can save the Corresponding Radio reponds to database using ajax...?is it will take more time with Lan ? i think maintaining the session & Cookies will be more difficult as Compare to saving it in database instantly and then if the user modify his answers we can make a update query.....is it will work ?

Answer (score 0):

sure can keep in db. would mean a lot of db updates but be fine if number of users using at same time is not huge. at back end use ejb or other txn mgt and db pool.

advantage is even if user does not complete you have part response.

Comment: I am Going to use HashMap to store the Responses but the problem is how can i store these Hashmap value(key/Value) in Session or Cookie? Please Help

Comment: can store the full hash map as a java object in the session.

Comment: for cookies will to json it or have a naming convention and store each question and each answer in a seperate cookie.

Comment: what if i store them in file system creating a file for particular user(based on Cookie or Session) n then  retrieve value from the file & destroy the file after final submission

Comment: i think data base or cookies will be more robust. for files unless you store files in sub folders for year and month, after time can be left with many un wanted files. also its more error prone in case of bad handling, but if you MUST, i suggest you look at java.util.Properties - use those instead of HashMap, use the getProperty and setProperty and store and load from there. Again will be better to use cookies at front end or a db at back end